# How to align flexbox to the left?

Tags: css, vue.js, flexbox

I am trying to move this FileCard component to the start. I tried using flex-start but the FileCards are still centered.

This is my code:

```
      <div
        v-if="posts"
        class="flex flex-wrap"
        style="justify-content: flex-start"
      >
        <BlogPost v-for="post in 5" :key="post" :blog="post"> </BlogPost>
      </div>
```

This is where I would like the FileCards to be.
[image]

Comment: Does removing the "Justify-content" not work ?

Comment: no it did not work. it is still the same

Comment: its looking like     "justify-content: center;" working from somewhere. try add justify-content-start class or can you add codes or link. we must see it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what your code looks like

```css
  .parent {
            background-color: blue;
            display: flex;
            /*  justify-content:flex-start; 
              justify-content: center;
                justify-content:space-between;
              */
            justify-content: space-around;
            width: 100%;
            flex-wrap: wrap;
        }

        .item {
            margin: 10px;
            width: 300px;
            height: 500px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: red;
        }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
        <div class="item"></div>
    </div>
```

removing justify-content or changing it to something else should work. You can check it in my code. so try changing it and see if you get different results if you didn't get any changes maybe post your CSS also

Answer (score 0):

your div element is getting "justify-content:space-around" from somewhere.
first, find it and then use "justify-content:left" or "justify-content:flex-start".
if it's still the same, then you should use "!important".

```
  <div
    v-if="posts"
    class="flex flex-wrap"
    style="justify-content: flex-start !important"
  >
    <!--or style="justify-content: left !important" -->
    <BlogPost v-for="post in 5" :key="post" :blog="post"> </BlogPost>
  </div>
```